# change shopify product page with liquid

Tags: shopify, themes, product, liquid

Hey I'm kinda new to this Shopify liquid stuff and while I'm learning the syntax i cant figure out how to add specific changes to an already made template of Shopify for example I'm using the sense theme and i want to edit the main product page(using theme kit) so it will have an option to upload an image for a canvas and that the image given will be shown instead of the main product default image, whats the best approach here? is using Shopify themes and coding from scratch a bad idea?

i have a short liquid script doing it(that i hope works cant check it) myself but cant understand where to add it in the file main-product

Answer (score 0):

If your theme is using formData webapi (The same method used to post product form in dawn theme), then you can upload images with your payload. But it has a drawback (as far as I looked it up). You cannot post multiple products with formData. At least I wasn't able to.